# What is the probability that the first time that the front and back of a fair coin appear an equal number of times is the $2n$th trial?

Tags: probability, combinatorics, stochastic-processes, random

> What is the probability that the first time that the front and back of a fair coin appear an equal number of times is the $2n$th trial?

The probability that the first time that the number of appearances front and back sides of the coin are equal ($n$ times each) after continuously throwing a fair coin $2n$ times is
$${\small \frac{1}{2n-1}\binom{2n}{n}\cdot\frac{1}{2^{2n}}=\frac{1}{2n-1}\cdot\frac{2n\cdot(2n-1)\cdots(n+1)}{n\cdot(n-1)\cdots 2\cdot 1}\cdot\frac{1}{4^n}.}$$
For example, take $n = 3$, that is, throw a fair coin $6$ times continuously. After two trials, it can't be "$1$ front side and $1$ back side" (only $2$ front sides or $2$ back sides); after the $4$th trial, it can't be $2$ front sides and $2$ back sides (only $3$ front sides and $1$ back side, or $1$ front side and $3$ back sides); after the $6$th trial, there are $3$ front sides and $3$ back sides (the number of appearances of the two sides are equal). The probability of this event is
$$\frac{1}{6-1}\cdot\frac{6\cdot5\cdot4}{3\cdot2\cdot 1}\cdot\frac{1}{4^3}=0.0625.$$
How to prove the above results?

Comment: I revised the description detail of the problem. Please see what you don't understand?

Comment: Are you asking for the probability that the first time that the number of times the front and back of coin have appeared an equal number of times is the $2n$th trial?

Comment: Yes, I mean that you said.

Comment: Question looks interesting.  I would probably try a generating function.

Comment: Have you heard of Catalan numbers and Dyck words?

Comment: It is the same as considering the $(+1,-1)$ random walk on $\mathbb Z$ and ask what is the probability of return in $2n$ steps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's consider a sequence of Bernouilli trials, with probability
$p$ of cuccess and $q= 1-p$ of failure, and let's represent it
as a path with steps $E-N$ on a square lattice.

[image: Catalan_Path_1]

Now you are looking for the probability of taking a path from $(0,0)$
which means also without crossing it.
So the possible paths are those which, apart from the initial
and the final leg, remain within the lower triangle $(1,0),(n,0),(n,n-1)$
or within the symmetrical upper triangle.

It is known that the number of  paths within each triangle is
given by the Catalan Number $C_{n-1}$.

Therefore the probability$ P(n)$ you are looking for is
$$
P(n) = 2p\left( {C_{n - 1} p^{n - 1} q^{n - 1} } \right)q =
 {2 \over n}\left( \matrix{  2\left( {n - 1} \right) \cr   n - 1 \cr}  \right)p^n q^n 
$$

which for $p=q=1/2$ and for  $n=1, 2, \cdots,6$ gives
$$
1/2, \; 1/8, \; 1/16, \; 5/128, \; 7/256, \; 21/1024
$$
which checks with computations.