# Proof for the identity $ \sum _{k=1}^j \frac{1}{2 k-1} \binom{2 k}{k} \binom{2 j-2 k}{j-k} =\binom{2 j}{j} $

Tags: summation, binomial-coefficients

I know that the following identity is true (e.g., using Mathematica)
$$
\sum _{k=1}^j \frac{1}{2 k-1} \binom{2 k}{k} \binom{2 j-2 k}{j-k} =\binom{2 j}{j}
$$
but I would like a proof of it, by any mean. I have tried by induction or with the following polynomial
$$
\sum _{k=1}^j \binom{2 k}{k} \binom{2 j-2 k}{j-k} x^{2k-2}
$$
with the intent of integrating it, but I had no luck in either case.

Thanks a lot for your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Given any infinite sequence of numbers
$\,\{t_0,t_1,\dots\},\,$ define the sequences
$$ a_n := t_n, \quad
   b_n := \frac{t_n}{2n-1}, \quad
   c_n := \sum_{k=1}^n a_{n-k}b_k. \tag{1} $$
Define their corresponding power series generating functions
$$ A := \sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n x^n, \quad
   B := \sum_{n=1}^\infty b_n x^n, \quad
   C := \sum_{n=1}^\infty c_n x^n. \tag{2} $$
Use the definitions in equation $(1)$ to get $\,A\,B = C.\,$
Define
$$ t_n := {2n\choose n}\qquad \text{ and }
\qquad y := \sqrt{1-4x}. \tag{3}$$
Use binomial coefficients results (
[OEIS A000984](https://oeis.org/A000984) and
[OEIS A002420](https://oeis.org/A002420)) to get
$$ A = \frac1y \qquad \text{ and } \qquad B = 1-y. \tag{4} $$
Multiply to get
$$ A\,B = \frac1y(1-y) = \frac1y - 1 = A-1. \tag{5} $$
Use $\,A\,B = C,\,$ to get
$\,c_n = a_n\,$ for all $\,n>0\,$
which proves the identity.

Answer (score 2):

We have
$$
\begin{align}
\left(1-4x^2\right)^{-1/2}
&=\sum_{n=0}^\infty(-4)^n\binom{-\frac12}{n}\,x^{2n}\tag{1a}\\
&=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\binom{2n}{n}\,x^{2n}\tag{1b}
\end{align}
$$
Subtracting $1$ and dividing by $x^2$ and integrating yields
$$
\begin{align}
\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac1{2n-1}\binom{2n}{n}\,x^{2n-1}
&=\int_0^x\frac{\left(1-4t^2\right)^{-1/2}-1}{t^2}\,\mathrm{d}t\tag{2a}\\
&=\int_0^x\frac{1-\left(1-4t^2\right)^{1/2}}{t^2\left(1-4t^2\right)^{1/2}}\,\mathrm{d}t\tag{2b}\\
&=\int_0^x\frac4{\left(1-4t^2\right)^{1/2}\left(1+\left(1-4t^2\right)^{1/2}\right)}\,\mathrm{d}t\tag{2c}\\
&=\int_0^x\frac2{\left(1-4t^2\right)^{1/2}+\left(1-4t^2\right)}\,\mathrm{d}(2t)\tag{2d}\\
&=\int_0^{\sin^{-1}(2x)}\frac2{1+\cos(u)}\,\mathrm{d}u\tag{2e}\\
&=\int_0^{\sin^{-1}(2x)}\frac2{\cos^2(u/2)}\,\mathrm{d}(u/2)\tag{2f}\\[6pt]
&=2\tan(\sin^{-1}(2x)/2)\tag{2g}\\[6pt]
&=\frac{1-\sqrt{1-4x^2}}x\tag{2h}
\end{align}
$$
Explanation:
$\text{(2a):}$ subtract $1$ from $(1)$, divide by $x^2$, and integrate
$\text{(2b):}$ multiply numerator and denominator by $\sqrt{1-4t^2}$
$\text{(2c):}$ multiply numerator and denominator by $1+\sqrt{1-4t^2}$
$\text{(2d):}$ collect terms
$\text{(2e):}$ $\sin(u)=2t$
$\text{(2f):}$ $\cos(u)=2\cos^2(u/2)-1$
$\text{(2g):}$ the integral of $\sec^2(x)$ is $\tan(x)$
$\text{(2h):}$ let $\sin(2\theta)=2x$, then $x=\sin(\theta)\cos(\theta)$
$\phantom{\text{(2h):}}$ therefore, $x=\frac{\tan(\theta)}{\sec^2(\theta)}=\frac{\tan(\theta)}{1+\tan^2(\theta)}$
$\phantom{\text{(2h):}}$ and thus, $2\tan(\theta)=\frac{1-\sqrt{1-4x^2}}x$

Multiplying $(2)$ by $x$ gives
$$
\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac1{2n-1}\binom{2n}{n}\,x^{2n}=1-{\textstyle\sqrt{1-4x^2}}\tag3
$$
Subtracting $1$ from $(1)$ gives
$$
\sum_{n=1}^\infty\binom{2n}{n}\,x^{2n}=\frac1{\sqrt{1-4x^2}}-1\tag4
$$
Multiplying $(3)$ and $(4)$ using the [Cauchy Product Formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy_product) yields
$$
\sum_{n=1}^\infty\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}\frac1{2k-1}\binom{2k}{k}\binom{2n-2k}{n-k}x^{2n}
=\frac1{\sqrt{1-4x^2}}+{\textstyle\sqrt{1-4x^2}}-2\tag5
$$
Noting that $(3)$ gives the missing $k=n$ term for $(5)$, if we add $(3)$ to $(5)$, we get
$$
\sum_{n=1}^\infty\sum_{k=1}^n\frac1{2k-1}\binom{2k}{k}\binom{2n-2k}{n-k}x^{2n}
=\frac1{\sqrt{1-4x^2}}-1\tag6
$$
Comparing the coefficients of $(4)$ and $(6)$ shows that for $n\ge1$,
$$
\sum_{k=1}^n\frac1{2k-1}\binom{2k}{k}\binom{2n-2k}{n-k}=\binom{2n}{n}\tag7
$$

Answer (score 2):

To prove such identities, I often prefer combinatorial approaches like "Double Counting" rather than "Snake Oil" or "WZ Pairs" methods. We will count the below quantity in two methods:

**The number of permutations of $j$ digits $0$ and $j$ digits $1$.**

- **First method:** Consider $2j$ places in a row. To create a such permutation, we can choose $j$ places and put $0$'s in these places. The rest places are owned by the $1$'s. So the number of ways of the first method is $\binom{2j}{j}$.
- **Second method:** For each $1 \leq k\leq j$, we count

  *the permutations of $j$ digits $0$ and $j$ digits $1$ such that "the number of $0$'s = the number of $1$'s" occurs for the first time at index $2k$.*

  It's easy to verify that when $k$ varies from $1$ to $j$, the above permutations contain all of the desired permutations, and they don't intersect each other. So let's count the number of such permutations for a fixed $k$. Suppose that there exist $a_k$ ways for the first $2k$ places. For the rest $2j - 2k$ places, we can choose $j - k$ of them and put $0$'s into them. Then the place of $1$'s will be determined uniquely. So the number of such permutations for a fixed $k$ is $a_k\binom{2j-2k}{j-k}$. Therefore, to complete the proof we only must show that $a_k = \frac{1}{2k-1}\binom{2k}{k}$.

  Suppose we are at the point $(0, 0)$ in the coordinate plane and for each digit $0$, we go a unit to the right and for each $1$, we go a unit to the up. So $a_k$ equals the number of ways we can reach $(k, k)$ such that we always walk strictly below the line $y = x$ or always strictly above this line. Oh! The famous [Catalan numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Catalan_number) appeared! One can easily see that the situation is equivalent to going from the point $(0, 1)$ to $(k, k-1)$ (or $(1, 0)$ to $(k-1, k)$) such that we always walk below (not necessary "strictly") the line $y = x - 1$ (or always above the line $y = x+1$). So $a_k = 2C_{k-1} = 2 \times \frac{1}{k}\binom{2k-2}{k-1} = \frac{1}{2k-1}\binom{2k}{k}$.

  [image]

  [Source](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4326077/what-is-the-probability-that-the-first-time-that-the-front-and-back-of-a-fair-co) of the picture

Answer (score 0):

$\newcommand{\bbx}[1]{\,\bbox[15px,border:1px groove navy]{\displaystyle{#1}}\,}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\,{#1}\,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\,{#1}\,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\dd}{\mathrm{d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,\mathrm{e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\ic}{\mathrm{i}}
 \newcommand{\mc}[1]{\mathcal{#1}}
 \newcommand{\mrm}[1]{\mathrm{#1}}
 \newcommand{\on}[1]{\operatorname{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\,{#1}\,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,{#2}\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{\mathrm{d}^{#1} #2}{\mathrm{d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\,{#1}\,\right\vert}$
$\ds{\bbox[5px,#ffd]{}}$

---

\begin{align}
&\bbox[5px,#ddf]{\left.\quad\sum_{k = 1}^{j}{1 \over 2k - 1}{2k \choose k}{2j - 2k \choose j - k}
\right\vert_{\, j\ \in\ \mathbb{N}_{\,\geq\ 1}}\quad }
\\[5mm] = & \
\sum_{k = 1}^{j}\pars{\int_{0}^{1}t^{2k - 2}\,\,\dd t}
\bracks{{-1/2 \choose k}\pars{-4}^{k}}
\bracks{{-1/2 \choose j - k}\pars{-4}^{j - k}}
\\[5mm] = & \
\pars{-4}^{j}\int_{0}^{1}\sum_{k = 1}^{\infty}
{-1/2 \choose k}{-1/2 \choose j - k}t^{2k - 2}\,\,\dd t
\\[5mm] = & \
\pars{-4}^{j}\int_{0}^{1}\sum_{k = 1}^{\infty}
{-1/2 \choose k}
\braces{\bracks{z^{j - k}}\pars{1 + z}^{-1/2}}
t^{2k - 2}\,\,\dd t
\\[5mm] = & \
\pars{-4}^{j}\bracks{z^{j}}\pars{1 + z}^{-1/2}\int_{0}^{1}\sum_{k = 1}^{\infty}
{-1/2 \choose k}\pars{zt^{2}}^{k}
\,\,{\dd t \over t^{2}}
\\[5mm] = & \
\pars{-4}^{j}\bracks{z^{j}}\pars{1 + z}^{-1/2}\int_{0}^{1}
{\pars{1 + zt^{2}}^{-1/2} - 1 \over t^{2}}\,\dd t
\\[5mm] = & \
\pars{-4}^{j}\bracks{z^{j}}\pars{1 + z}^{-1/2}
\bracks{1 - \pars{1 + z}^{1/2}}
\\[5mm] = & \
\pars{-4}^{j}\braces{\bracks{z^{j}}\pars{1 + z}^{-1/2}
- \bracks{z^{j}}1}
\\[5mm] = & \
\pars{-4}^{j}{-1/2 \choose j} =
\pars{-4}^{j}{{2j \choose j} \over \pars{-4}^{j}}=
\bbx{\large2j \choose j}
\end{align}